# ArrayList doesn't produce what we want

Tags: java

we are working on a little project for 2nd semeseter java stuff and tried to fix a bug for like 1 hour now. We can't do it. Our problem is the following:

- We have to program a little halma game with variable board size, variable number of players and KI. Currently we fail at calculating the exact start areas for each player.

This is what our function looks like:

```
/**
 * Calculates a standard Start area as seen in the task definition dependend on the number of
 * figures we want according to the number of players
 * @return list of cells
 */
public ArrayList<Cell> calculateArea(int modifier) {
    ArrayList<Cell> cells = new ArrayList<Cell>();

    for (int x = 0; x <= 4 - modifier; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y <= 4 - modifier; y++) {
            if (y <= 1){
                cells.add(new Cell(x, y));
            }
            else if (y == 2) {
                if(x <= 3 - modifier) {
                    cells.add(new Cell(x, y));
                }
                else {
                    break;
                }                   
            }
            else if (y == 3) {
                if (x <= 2 - modifier) {
                    cells.add(new Cell(x, y));
                }
                else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            else if (y == 4) {
                if(x <= 1) {
                    cells.add(new Cell(x, y));
                }
                else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return cells;
}
```

This will output an array of cells which are considered to be the starting area of the top left player (Its a square board).

After that we try to rotate the calculated starting area according to board size and where the current player is playing at with this function:

```
/**
 * Rotates a given area of Cells to the right according to board size
 * is used to calculate Starting and Target areas for each player
 * @param area
 * @return
 */
private ArrayList<Cell> rotateRight(ArrayList<Cell> area, int modifier) {
    for(Cell c : area) {
        if(modifier == 0) {
            // 19 Figures
            if(c.getY() <= 1) {
                c.setX(c.getX() + Board.getSize() - 5);
            }
            else if(c.getY() == 2) {
                c.setX(c.getX() + Board.getSize() - 4);
            }
            else if(c.getY() == 3) {
                c.setX(c.getX() + Board.getSize() - 3);
            }
            else {
                c.setX(c.getX() + Board.getSize() - 2);
            }
        }
        else {
            // 13 Figures
            if(c.getY() <= 1) {
                c.setX(c.getX() + Board.getSize() - 4);
            }
            else if(c.getY() == 2) {
                c.setX(c.getX() + Board.getSize() - 3);
            }
            else if(c.getY() == 3) {
                c.setX(c.getX() + Board.getSize() - 2);
            }
        }               
    }
    return area;
}

/**
 * Rotates a given area of Cells down according to board size
 * is used to calculate Starting and Target areas for each player
 * @param area
 * @return
 */
private ArrayList<Cell> rotateDown(ArrayList<Cell> area, int modifier) {
    for(Cell c : area) {
        if(modifier == 0) {
            // 19 Figures
            if(c.getX() <= 1) {
                c.setY(c.getY() + Board.getSize() - 5);
            }
            else if(c.getX() == 2) {
                c.setY(c.getY() + Board.getSize() - 4);
            }
            else if(c.getX() == 3) {
                c.setY(c.getY() + Board.getSize() - 3);
            }
            else {
                c.setY(c.getY() + Board.getSize() - 2);
            }
        }
        else {
            // 13 Figures
            if(c.getX() <= 1) {
                c.setY(c.getY() + Board.getSize() - 4);
            }
            else if(c.getX() == 2) {
                c.setY(c.getY() + Board.getSize() - 3);
            }
            else if(c.getX() == 3) {
                c.setY(c.getY() + Board.getSize() - 2);
            }
        }
    }
    return area;
}
```

There are 2 problems:
- It seem's that all the locations (start and target) for each player share the same values. Which means all arrayLists in each player link to the same object on the heap. I guess we have to somehow deep copy the ArrayList each time before we actually rotate it?

- Somehow it doesn't generate the correct values for each location even though we checked those functions for like one hour. Where is our mistake, if the board is 16x16 in size?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hm, one hour seems not so much for me. Don't give up. You recognized already the first problem. If your intention for method `rotateRight()` was to leave the input list unchanged, then you have to copy the list first (deep copy). You can create a new `ArrayList` with the same size and clone each `Cell` instance of your original list. Look at [Object.clone()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()) and interface [Clonable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html).

Comment: For the second problem we need more information about what you expected and where your actual data differs. Your data structure is not self-explanatory. We even don't know, what `Board` and `Cell` is exactly and how the list of `Cell` objects relates to the real game.

Comment: For 16x16 board game the first data structure for the model is a two dimensional array of cells that comes into my mind. Why do you use a `ArrayList`? It's only one dimension.